# How to build shortcut that filters for early reminder

Tags: ios, shortcut, reminders

How can I build a shortcut that filters for all reminders that have an early reminder where the early reminder is the current date and time or after the current date and time and add that reminder to a list I previously created to keep track of them.

This is for the reminders app on ios

What I am mostly interested in is being able to edit a reminder I find that has an early reminder with current date today and time or early reminder date is in the past if that’s even possible.